# Is there a tool to generate call graph from Lua script?

Tags: lua, call-graph

Is there a tool similar to `pycallgraph` for Lua?

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/c0cdccdbf2c6a2cb4bdb) which is static only and does not span across multiple files.

Comment: FWIW, `across multiple files` is tricky in Lua - when you call a global symbol, it is only resolved at runtime, where any symbol might have any meaning (any function associated with it) even on different loop iterations within the same invocation.

Comment: This might also be effective for functions within the same file, which is not declared local.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

[luaflow](https://github.com/calio/luaflow): A tool like GNU cflow but for Lua programming language